# Express drops connection after 2 minutes

Tags: php, express

I have a PHP Script that connects to Express (Node) running a `setInterval`.
This is being accessed through cUrl, so it'll look something like this:

```
$status = curl(http://example.com/status?id=xyz);
$status = json_decode(status, true);
if ($status[success] == true) { 
  //Do stuff here
}
```

Express is picking the request up the following way:

```
app.get('/status/', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.query['id'];
  var statusInterval = setInterval(getStatus, 30 * 1000)
  var statusTimeout = setTimeout(function() { //Clears Interval after 15m
    clearInterval(statusInterval)
  }, 15 * 60 * 1000);
});
```

however, after 2 minutes the connection randomly drops and `else` is being executed.
Setting `max_execution_time` in the PHP.ini to 600 (10 Minutes) didn't help, nor did `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` or `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`.

Comment: you could try posting real code, and *what makes you believe that it is not your express that snips out the long connection* ?

Comment: I edited my Post to reflect the code more clearly, I hope it's okay like this. What I haven't thought about is express acting up because everything sent to php was logged and didn't report any errors, however, I will look into that again in case I've missed anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out what Yves had suggested was correct - although not properly mentioned in the docs before, there is a timeout set in place by express that closes connections after 120 Seconds thorugh a `setTimeout`.

To prevent this, simply void the timeout by adding

```
res.connection.setTimeout(0);
```

to your function.

The issue is described - in a more detailed manner - on https://contourline.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/preventing-server-timeout-in-node-js/